# CQRSLite and MassTransit integration

Tags: message-queue, cqrs, masstransit, event-sourcing

I'm currently playing with [CQRSLite](https://github.com/gautema/CQRSlite) framework and curious how to use MassTransit as a bus implementation.

The problem, that I'm currently have, how to properly register consumers on MassTransit side in order to route messages (commands and events) to handlers like this

```
public class InventoryCommandHandlers : ICommandHandler<CreateInventoryItem>
{
    public void Handle(CreateInventoryItem message)
    {
        // do some job...
    }
}

public class InventoryListView : IEventHandler<InventoryItemCreated>
{
    public void Handle(InventoryItemCreated message)
    {
        // do some job...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can always implement two interfaces:

```
public class InventoryCommandHandlers : 
    ICommandHandler<CreateInventoryItem>,
    IConsumer<CreateInventoryItem>
{
    public void Handle(CreateInventoryItem message)
    {
        // do some job...
    }

    public Task Consume(CreateInventoryItem message)
    {
        Handle(message);
        return Task.FromResult(true);
    }
}

public class InventoryListView : 
     IEventHandler<InventoryItemCreated>,
     IConsumer<InventoryItemCreated>
{
    public void Handle(InventoryItemCreated message)
    {
        // do some job...
    }

    public Task Consume(InventoryItemCreated message)
    {
        Handle(message);
        return Task.FromResult(true);
    }
}
```

**However** CQRSLite seems to be designed for in-process use, don't really see any benefit in using it in distributed context.

I would strongly suggest looking at the original m-r repository and implement your own base library, it only takes 1/2 day and you get way better understanding how thing work.

You can also look at [AggregateSource](https://github.com/yreynhout/AggregateSource) and [Projac](https://github.com/yreynhout/Projac) to get some inspiration and may be even get them in use, these are very good examples.

Comment: Thanks, Alexey! CQRSLite doesn't seem to me as for in-process use only. It has pretty good abstractions separation, so in a proper implementation it should work fine. Two interfaces of course an option, but in this case I'll couple the code to MassTransit instead of just do that connection in Bus only implementation. Looks like I should take a look on direct communication with RabbitMQ without MT. Thanks for the shared links as well, will take a look on them too :)

Comment: We are using MassTransit as command transport and cross-BC domain events transport in many projects with great success. I am not sure how using RabbitMQ client will help you there to be honest. Command handlers are exactly between your infrastructure and domain model so if command handlers consume MT messages - it is perfectly fine.

Comment: My assumption about CQRSLite to be in-process comes from its similarity with MediatR in terms of command/event handling.

Comment: Remember that MT is not only abstracting the transport but allow you to test better, use advanced patters like retry policies, sagas, routing slip, turnout and do pub/sub with a breeze.